# How to subtract two lines inside a dataset

Tags: dataset, matlab

SO what i'm trying to do is get it to subtract two columns of my [dataset](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html) which is a matrix of 50x9.

I want it to subtract the last column from the 5th to see the difference and to put it into a new variable. And then make the variable into a bar graph.

However I keep getting an error that I'm not allowed to use a minus sign. Any ideas?

```
data=dataset('File', 'thegrid2.txt', 'Delimiter', ',');
[rows cols] = size(data);
x= 1:1:10;
a= data(:,5);
b= data(:,9);
y= b - a;
bar(x,y)
```

Comment: what does `class(data)` yield ?

Comment: @Lama this is the `dataset` class from the statistics toolbox

Answer (score 1):

try to convert the columns to double:

```
a = double(data(:,5));
b = double(data(:,9));
y = b - a;
```

also I think `x` should match the lenght of `y`:

```
x = 1:numel(y);
```

---

Here are two more ways to index into the [`dataset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html) object:

```
%# use variable names
vars = get(data,'VarNames');
y = data.(vars{5}) - data.(vars{9});
```

or simply as:

```
%# use integer index
y = data.(5) - data.(9);
```